# Bootstrap collapse plugin - how to collapse sideways

Tags: jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I wish to collapse an area to the right (horizontally) rather then collapse vertically. Is there a way to set that via the bootstrap plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the JQuery [animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) on width. It was not hard to implement but what I liked about the bootstrap solution is that it is all in the class attributes. Too bad it seems to only work vertically.